# How to get values from pojo list

Tags: java, hibernate, list, spring-mvc

I am storing values of below query is a list which having type pojo class. I need to get each videos from vList.And I wants How can I retrive in a loop. 
Dao.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Videos> getFullVideoList(long albumid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // albumid=11;
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx=session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery( "from Videos where  videoStatus=1");
    query.setParameter("albumid", albumid).setParameter("videotype","VDSG");;
    List<Videos> vList=query.list();
tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return vList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply iterate it using any loop

if the size of the list is too large, then don't use .list() method.
You may get outOfMemory error.

Instead use statelesssession and scrollable resultset. This will be more fast and efficient.

Comment: Could you please help me with an example

Comment: for(Videos v: vList){
-----
------
}

Comment: `StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   
ScrollableResults videos= session.createQuery( "from Videos where  videoStatus=1");
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while ( videos.next() ) {
    Videoscustomer = (Videos) videos.get(0);
    ----- 
   -----
}
   
tx.commit();
session.close();`

Comment: please follow this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

its similar to basic JDBC with added hibernate feature.